# what are ${} in config.ini

Tags: python, configuration

I've been reading code base develop by someone else. In one of the config_file.ini it contains

```
[key]
id = John
pwd = 123123
server = ${common:prefix}server_name
```

What exactly is ${} doing? Also if there is reference that talks about it please let me know.

Comment: You don't say what program is reading the config file. If it is a Python program, it is likely it is using `configparser`. That is documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's documented under [`configparser.ExtendedInterpolation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ExtendedInterpolation). It's a syntax(`${section:option}`) to denote a value from a foreign section. For example, in the following config file the `path` option also refers to the `system_dir` value from `Common` section.

```
[Common]
home_dir: /Users
library_dir: /Library
system_dir: /System
macports_dir: /opt/local
    
[Frameworks]
Python: 3.2
path: ${Common:system_dir}/Library/Frameworks/
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```